# Azure Relay Hybrid Connection Scale Out

Tags: azure, azure-servicebusrelay

Given the standard hybrid OnPrem/Cloud scenario where we have multiple OnPrem clients connecting to a service in the cloud, how can we service them all from a scaled out service (i.e. multiple listeners servicing multiple clients)?

Say we have a cloud service that implements the Hybrid Relay listener, and to service all of our clients we scale it out to N instances(up to 25).  Clients get assigned to each instance via the documented load balancing feature so that each listener services a portion of the clients.  What if we need to broadcast messages to all of the clients (like a chat application)?  As far as I can tell, any single listener never has access to all of the client connections.  Am I missing something?

I've used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-dotnet-get-started as an example to play around with this scenario by standing up multiple servers (listeners) with multiple clients (connections) connecting to each server, but there doesn't seem to be a way to broadcast or lookup ALL of the connections to the namespace, only the connections in the current listener scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but there doesn't seem to be a way to broadcast or lookup ALL of the connections to the namespace, only the connections in the current listener scope.

Message transfer of Azure Relay Hybrid is based on the connection. If a client is not connected to a server,  we can't send message to the client from the server.

For the broadcast scenario, I suggest you use Azure Service Bus topics. After created a topic, you could subscribe this topic for all the clients. When we send a message to the topic, all the subscriptions will receive the message.

For how to use Azure Service Bus topics, link below is for your reference.

[Get started with Service Bus topics(.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions)